# AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'Class_Name' in def CheckStock(myUrl,model)

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I am having trouble finding a class in the adidas website. I get error above when trying to find class in html. I am trying to automate the process of choosing a specific size with my shoebot. When I inspect the html code the class I find in the code is what I wrote in the code. Am I calling out the class incorrectly?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def UrlGenwithSize(size,model,name):
    base=580                   ####size of shoe
    mysize=(size-4)*20         #### for a shoe of size 6.5
    finalSize=base+mysize
    Url="https://www.adidas.com/us/"+name+"/"+model+".html?forceSelSize="+model+"_"+str(finalSize)
    return Url

def UrlGenProduct(name,model):
    url="https://www.adidas.com/us/"+name+"/"+model+".html"
    return url

def CheckStock(myUrl,model):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_bot\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(myUrl)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Class_Name, "size-selector___2htsB")))  ###sets a time max of 10 secs and waits for the elements
        username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sizes___3Stmf fractions-decoration-reset___22Rwq')
        buttons = username.find_elements_by_tag_name("button") ###get all the options into a list
        buttonsList = []
        for button in buttons:
            buttonsList.append(button.get_attribute('innerHTML')) ###a list with sizes
        for sizes in buttonsList:
            if sizes.isdigit(): ###printing only if size in the list is a digit
                print("Size" + sizes + "for" + model + "is available")
    finally:
        driver.quit()

url=UrlGenProduct("Kaptir Shoes","EE9513")
CheckStock(url,"EE9513")
size=int(input("Please enter size"))
myURL=UrlGenwithSize(6.5,"EE9513","Kaptir Shoes")
addToCart(myURL)
```

Comment: Use this By.CLASS_NAME it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try UPPER letters

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "size-selector___2htsB")))
```